# Policy Based Routing Not Working

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

We've just implemented a secondary internet connection. It will be used as pure failover so for the time being I just want to avoid async routing issues.

I've setup 2 routing tables:

```
fw1 ~ # ip route sho tabl 10 | grep default
default via 59.167.xx.xx dev eth0  src 59.167.xx.xx
fw1 ~ # ip route sho tabl 20 | grep default
default via 115.64.xx.xx dev eth0.2  src 115.64.xx.xx
```

Table 10 is our primary connection, Table 20 is the new connection. I've setup the rules to select the routing table based on the connection mark:

```
fw1 ~ # ip rule sho
0:  from all lookup local 
32736:  from all fwmark 0x14 lookup 20 
32737:  from all fwmark 0xa lookup 10 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

The appropriate rules are also setup in iptables:

```
fw1 ~ # iptables -t mangle -nvL PREROUTING
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 300K packets, 164M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 372K  201M CONNMARK   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           CONNMARK restore 
 371K  201M PBR        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* this stream has no mark; send it to the PBR chain */ mark match 0x0 
fw1 ~ # iptables -t mangle -nvL PBR
Chain PBR (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   10   666 MARK-gw1   all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            59.167.xx.xx/29    /* prevent asynchronous routing */ state NEW mark match 0x0 
   18  1128 MARK-gw2   all  --  eth0.2 *       0.0.0.0/0            115.64.xx.xx/29    /* prevent asynchronous routing */ state NEW mark match 0x0 
fw1 ~ # iptables -t mangle -nvL MARK-gw1
Chain MARK-gw1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   10   666 MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* send via 59.167.xx.xx */ MARK set 0xa 
   10   666 CONNMARK   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           CONNMARK save 
   10   666 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
fw1 ~ # iptables -t mangle -nvL MARK-gw2
Chain MARK-gw2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   18  1128 MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* send via 115.64.xx.xx */ MARK set 0x14 
   18  1128 CONNMARK   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           CONNMARK save 
   18  1128 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I'm testing with a ping from an outside VPS. The connection tracking table confirms that the mark is being set correctly:

```
icmp     1 28 src=173.255.xx.xx dst=115.64.xx.xx type=8 code=0 id=29301 src=115.64.xx.xx dst=173.255.xx.xx type=0 code=0 id=29301 mark=20 secmark=0 use=2
```

But tcpdump shows the reply being sent via eth0 instead of eth0.2 even though it has the correct source address:

```
fw1 ~ # tcpdump -lnn -i eth0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
14:07:56.429765 IP 115.64.xx.xx > 173.255.xx.xx: ICMP echo reply, id 29301, seq 619, length 64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know exactly why mine didn't work, but I reimplemented it using the 'throw default' option as per this [1] guide. I know I shouldn't link to an external site as an answer but it's way too long to copy and paste here I'm sorry.

[1] http://www.cyber.com.au/~twb/doc/dual-uplink.txt